# SSRS 2008 R2 Sparkline Based on CSV String of Values

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008-r2

I would like to know if it is possible to create a chart/graph based on a comma separated list of values. There would only be 1 series and this would be a sparkline chart so I really don't care to see either axis...just a line going up or down.

Example input from the database table: 1,2,3,4,5
This example should produce 1 line which increases in value from left to right.

If needed, I am open to custom code in SSRS to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS you can point chart only to dataset.
I recommend you convert your comma separated data into xml and then shred your xml data into relation data like this:

```
WITH ChartData AS
(
    SELECT '1,3,5,4' AS YValues
),
ShrededChartData AS
(
    SELECT Y.value('.','int') AS YValues
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT CAST(N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(YValues,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML) XMLValues
        FROM ChartData 
    ) AS XMLChartData 
    CROSS APPLY XMLValues.nodes('//root/r') AS XmlTable(Y)
)
SELECT YValues
FROM ShrededChartData
```

Then create dataset based on this query and point this dataset to your chart.

Comment: Thanks Roman. This isn't XML data though. It would be data from a DB column (stored as a string). So the chart can be based on a dataset but somehow I need to parse out the CSV string (not in the database...i know about split and things to get rows from CSV data).

Comment: I don't see a problem, in my query I convert comma separated values into xml, why you can't do so? Can you describe the way by which you get data from CSV? Meybe after this I'll be able to give you better answer.

Comment: this isn't a CSV file...just a comma separated string value. The database column contains "1,2,3,4,5" stored as a varchar(max). only 1 row of data will exist in the dataset...not multiple rows like in your example.

Comment: The dataset query in my case would be "SELECT '1,3,5,4' AS YValues". That's all. Can't split it out into multiple rows like your example does. I am trying to determine if SSRS itself can deal with "1,3,5,4" without splitting it in the database.

Comment: In the beginning I've pointed that ssrs charts can't deal with  arrays, only with dataset. Can you explain why you can't split this values into multiple rows? I can't get the reason to work with comma separated values instead of dataset.